# Interchanging a limit and a parametric improper integral

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

Suppose I have the limit:
$$\lim _{t\to 0^+}\int _0^{\sqrt{\sqrt{t}+4}}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\:dx$$
How can I prove that the limit is $2$? It is easy to prove that for all $t > 0$ the improper inegral converges by using the limit comparison test (the problem is at x = 0). I also see that the upper bound approaches $2$. If I try to write the improper integral as a limit of a proper integral I get: $$\lim _{t\to 0^+}\:\left(\lim _{a\to 0^+}\int _a^{\sqrt{\sqrt{t}+4}}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\:dx\right)$$ However, I don't know how to deal with an iterated limit. When can I switch the order? Is it even the proper way to tackle the limit? Note that I haven't learned measure theory so I would prefer a solution which doesn't require it.

Comment: You can replace $t$ with $0$, resulting in $\int _0^{2}1\:dx$. (Can anyone tell me whether I should post this as an answer or it is better to be a comment as it is too short)?

Comment: @RamanujanXV So how do you know this improper integral is continuous (from the right at least) as a function of $t$?

Comment: You could prove this with the dominated convergence theorem, but since you want to avoid measure theory see answer below.

Comment: You can apply squeeze on integrand by using $\sqrt{1+a}<1+(a/2)$. See details in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove the limit is $2$ we must show that for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < t < \delta$, then

$$\tag{*}\left|\int _0^{\sqrt{\sqrt{t}+4}}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\,dx -2 \right| < \epsilon$$

Note that

$$\left|\int _0^{\sqrt{\sqrt{t}+4}}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\,dx -2 \right| \leqslant \left|\int _2^{\sqrt{\sqrt{t}+4}}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\,dx + \int _0^{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\,dx -2 \right|\\ \leqslant \underbrace{\left|\int _2^{\sqrt{\sqrt{t}+4}}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\,dx\right|}_{A} + \underbrace{\left|\int _0^{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\,dx -2 \right|}_{B}$$

For the term $A$, with $x \geqslant 2$ we have

$$A=\left|\int _2^{\sqrt{\sqrt{t}+4}}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\,dx\right|\leqslant \sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{2}}}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{t}+4}-2\right)$$

Since the RHS depends continuously on $t$ there exists $\delta_1>0 $ such that if $0< t < \delta_1$, then $A < \epsilon/2$.

Term $B$ is easily handled by showing that the improper integral converges uniformly for $t$ in any bounded interval $[0,C]$. Since $\left|\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\right| \leqslant \sqrt{1+\frac{C}{4\sqrt{x}}}$ it follows by the Weierstrass M-test that the improper integral appearing in $B$ is uniformly convergent and, thus,

$$\lim_{t \to 0+}\int _0^{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\,dx = \int_0^2\lim_{t \to 0+}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\,dx  = 2$$

Hence, there exists $\delta_2 > 0$ such that when $0 < t < \delta_2$ we have

$$B = \left|\int _0^{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\,dx -2 \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Therefore, we conclude the limit is $2$ since if $0 < t < \delta = \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$, then

$$\left|\int _0^{\sqrt{\sqrt{t}+4}}\sqrt{1+\frac{t}{4\sqrt{x}}}\,dx -2 \right|  \leqslant A + B < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon,$$

---

Here we have used a well-known theorem:

> If $f:(a,b] \times S \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and the improper
> integral $$F(t) =\int_a^b f(x,t)\,dx = \lim_{c \to a+}\int_c^b f(x,t)
>  \, dx$$ is uniformly convergent for $t \in S$, then $F:S \to
>  \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $S$.

To prove this  we consider the sequence $(F_n)$ given by

$$F_n(t) = \int_{a + 1/n}^b f(x,t) \, dt$$

Then $F_n(t) \to F(t)$ and the covergence is uniform since the improper integral converges uniformly.  Furthermore each $F_n$ is continuous.   This implies that the limit finction $F$ must be continuous (by another elementary theorem of real analysis).

Comment: Which theorem allows you to interchange the limit and the integral? (You did it right after writing about the M test). Can you quote the theorem or name it please?

Comment: @Algo: As you can see, I first removed the problem associated with the variable upper limit and left this to consideration of switching the limit and the improper integral over a fixed interval $[0,2]$.  The theorem is found in most real analysis books in various forms.  For example Theorem 33.6 in The Elements of Real Analysis (2nd. Ed.) by Bartle. It states that if $f:[a,b]\times S \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $F(t) = \int_a^b f(x,t) \, dx$ converges uniformly for $t \in S$ then $F$ is continuous on $S$.

Comment: That of course implies that if $0 \in S$, then $\lim_{t \to 0} F(s) = F(0) = \int_a^b f(x,0) \, dx$ .   I can add some more detail to the answer.

Comment: But in our case $f$ is not a function from $[0,2] \times S$, since it is not defined for $x = 0$. That's what boggles me.

Comment: Let me be more clear.  All of these conditions can be weakened when using the dominated convergence theorem -- but you don't want that -- so the strong conditions applying here are Let $f :(a,b]\times S \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.  Note that I have a half-open interval $(a,b]$.  The integral $\int_a^b f(x,t) \, dx$ is improper in this case due to behavior at $a$.  The theorem still applies.   I'll give you a proof above.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, you are the best! You are litteraly on every question on MSE. I better start learning measure theory and then the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @Algo:  You don't need measure theory here. It is important at this stage for you to understand the proof without it to get firmly grounded in analysis.  Also what this problem is really about is separating out the problem of the variable upper limit.

Comment: Do you have some good analysis books to recommend?

Comment: @Algo: I like the old standard books.  Besides Bartle there is Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin and Mathematical Analysis by Apostol.  Bartle has a better treatment of convergence / uniform convergence of improper integrals depending on a parameter.  You can learn a lot from classic books like Introduction to the Theory of Infinite Series by Bromwich and The Theory of Functions by Titchmarsh.

Answer (score 2):

Use the substitution $u^2=\sqrt{t}+4$ so that $u\to 2^+$ and the integral is reduced to $$\int_0^u\sqrt{1+\frac{(u^2-4)^2}{4\sqrt{x}}}\,dx$$ Let the integrand be denoted by $f(u, x) $ then we have $$0\leq f(u, x) - 1=\frac{(u^2-4)}{4\sqrt{x}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{1+\dfrac{(u^2-4)^2}{4\sqrt{x}}}}\leq \frac{(u^2-4)^2}{8\sqrt{x}}$$ Thus we get $$1\leq f(u, x) \leq 1+\frac{(u^2-4)^2}{8\sqrt{x}}$$ Integrating with respect to $x$ on $[0,u]$ we get $$u\leq \int_0^u f(u, x) \, dx\leq u+\frac{(u^2-4)^2\sqrt{u}}{4}$$ Letting $u\to 2^+$ we get desired limit as $2$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer